# Weird behavior of NERDTreeFind function

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, plugin-nerdtree

I have keymap in my `init.vim` file

```
nmap <silent> <leader>y :call NERDTreeFind()<cr>
```

It opens a default file in the `NERDTree` window from vim's command line by typing `:NERDTreeFind` as it expected.

But when I'm pressing the shortcut `<leader>y` I got this message:

```
E117: Unknown function: NERDTreeFind
```

What might be a problem here?

I'm using `neovim` under OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the [documentation](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERDTree.txt), `NERDTreeFind` is a command, not a function. This means you do not need `:call`.

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>y :NERDTreeFind<cr>
```

Comment: +1 for the `nnoremap` spot.